# Resume wav recording even after application was closed?

Tags: c#, audio, wav, recording, resume

I have built a basic sound recorder in C# Winform with a play and pause button.
It all works great but what I need it to do is somehow save / remember the current position of the recording where it was paused and then resume after that position, even if the application was closed. Is this possible at all without using a database? If so please shed a little more light on it. My code as below:

```
public void button1_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {          

        record("open new Type waveaudio Alias recsound", "", 0, 0);

        record("record recsound", "", 0, 0);
    }

 private void button7_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        record("pause recsound", "", 0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: You're going to have to save your location in the wav file somehow, either to a file or to a database and then read that location when you restart your application. Obviously you're going to need to indicate to the application that it was closed in the middle of the process so it knows to resume from that location.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. How would I go about saving the "stat" or current position of the recording in a file locally or on a network share? I am trying to stay away from having to create a database altogether. Thank you in advance for any solutions.

Comment: Just save the path of the file and the location (say the number of milliseconds) inside it in a simple file. It can even be a text file or you could use XML or whatever type you want. Do a search for working with files C# or saving files and you will find all the examples you need.